# Почему программа считает уравнение не правильно?(c#)

Tags: c#

В этом коде при написании любого уравнения выводит 43 хотя должно явно выводить другой ответ:

```
using System;

namespace Math_function
{
    class Expression
    {
        public Expression(string exp)
        {
            char[] ch = exp.ToCharArray();
            Console.WriteLine(ch);
            int res = 0;
            if (ch != null)
            {
                foreach (char i in ch)
                {
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case '+':
                            res += (int)i;
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }
            //Выводит 43
            Console.WriteLine(res);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не должен. Для другого ответа нужен другой код.

---

Вот что делает этот код:

- пройти по всем символам строки,
- если символ "+", добавить его код (43) к результату,
- вывести результат.

Comment: Я понял. Огромное спасибо

Comment: @NormalName Пожалуйста. Успехов. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.